# Immutable js make list from map of lists

Tags: javascript, immutable.js

I have an Immutable js map of lists.  I want to convert it to a list of the first items from every key

```
{keyA:[item1A,item2A,item3A],keyB:[item1B,item2B,item3B]}
```

to

```
[item1A,item1B]
```

Answer (score 2):

There is certainly a way to do this with Immutable and it’s even a one-liner. You can just convert the map to a `List` using `toList()` and then use `map` and/or `filter` however you like.

```
const myMapOfLists = fromJS(
  {
    item1: [{id: 1}, {id: 2}, {id: 3}],
    item2: [{id: 4}, {id: 5}, {id: 6}],
    item3: [{id: 7}, {id: 8}, {id: 9}],
  }
);
const myNewList = myMapOfLists.toList().map(item => item.get(0));
// console.log(myNewList.toJS());
// => [{id: 1}, {id: 4}, {id: 7}];
```

Please note that this code is error prone. For example, what if item2 wasn’t a List? You can simply avoid these issues by checking if an item is a List using Immutable’s `isList()` method.